# How to add to a compound text index on live database without affecting users dependent on the existing text index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a live mongoDB that has a compound index containing 5 text fields we want to be able to search on.  I want to add a new field into this index so that we can additionally search on the new field.

I can't add a new index, since only one text index is supported per collection in a mongodb.  I could remove the existing index, then create a new index that is identical to the old except with the new value added to it.

However, this is a large database and the search functionality is utilized regularly by users to search for relevant data.  If I remove the index, even briefly, then users would find their attempts to search slowed significantly until the new index has been built.  I'm not sure how long it would take to build the new index, and thus I'm worried about the impact this may have on our live system.

What is the cleanest way to append to my existing index that minimizes the odds that users dependent on the index will be affected by the transition?

Comment: There is no way to modify an existing text index (see: [Modify an Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/#modify-an-index)). In case you plan to drop and re-create the text index, with multiple fields, you can consider [Wildcard Text Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes).